# Stretchable white space in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, typesetting

In one of my Google Sheets I have the following formula:

```
="Azarenka: "&countif(B$9:B,"Azarenka")
```

that is rendered like

```
| Azarenka: 4       |
```

but I'd prefer to have the equivalent of an `\hfill` in TeX

```
| Azarenka:       4 |
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not possible without some scripts reading the column width in pixels.

Why not have a column for the names, and another column with the scores?  Then get rid of gridlines (View>Gridlines>uncheck).  Then add some borders in the appropriate places and color to get the right effect?